# read mp4 by fs JavaScript in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to read mp4 file as 4D array (RGB, width, height and time) by fs or any other package in JavaScript in firebase cloud function.

```
exports.readNewVideo = functions.storage
    .object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
        const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), object.name);
        await bucket.file(object.name!).download({ destination: tempFilePath });
        // read here by tempFilePath 
    });
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried. If your code works and file gets saved to temp directory you should be able to read with fs module.

Comment: @EmilGi yes, I can read my file but not as 3D array of pixels